# How to disable gcc error colors in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I want to copy my linux terminal output to a file. The terminal output contains gcc errors which are colored due to which I am seeing special characters in my text output file.

What can I do to avoid this ?

I am using following command

```
mycommand 2>&1 | tee filename.txt
```

I am fine with disabling color or either having an output file with colors.

Comment: gcc disables coloring when outputting to pipe

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I am seeing special characters like ^[m^[K

Comment: What's the correlation between `gcc` and `mycommand`?

Comment: There is no `gcc` command shown in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the gcc flag `-fdiagnostics-color=never` or `-fno-diagnostics-color`.